# Creating a VSCode snippet to "Capitalize" a duplicate tabstop inside a placeholder tabstop

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

## This question has been answered below by @Mark, please do not mark as closed with a need for "details or clarity". See the answer, which succinctly and accurately solved my problem.

I want to create a VSCode user snippet that will help me build a button element in my html.

My issue is that I need to have the outputted placeholder value capitalized.

Here's my current progress:

Existing Snippet:

```
"<button type=\"${1|button,submit|}\" name=\"$2\" class=\"btn $2\">${3:$2}</button>"
```

Current Output:

```
<button type="button" name="demo" class="btn demo">demo</button>
```

Desired Output:

```
<button type="button" name="demo" class="btn demo">Demo</button>
```

(The only difference is that the "D" in the text of the button is in upper case.)

Note: Once implemented, I need a solution in which "Demo" (in the above example) will remain a placeholder, so that it can be quickly overridden if necessary!

Comment: Please don't use all kinds of unnecessary formatting when asking your question. It does nothing but distract from the readability, and you want people to read your question. :-) Use code markup where appropriate, and emphasis where you're **really** emphasizing something, not for whole paragraphs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why did you close this question? I'd love some context so that I can better use SO.

Comment: **I** didn't, three people combined (including me) did. Which is odd, because I thought I'd retracted my close vote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`"<button type=\"${1|button,submit|}\" name=\"$2\" class=\"btn $2\">${3:${2/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}}</button>",`

it does the capitalization, still working on the selection.  I think there is a bug - the above code should work but the final tabstop $3 is not selected as it should be.  If I just insert a `space` within the $3 tabstop just before the $2 transform as in the below it works perfectly fine - but that shouldn't make any difference, but of course then there is an extra space in the output:

```
   "<button type=\"${1|button,submit|}\" name=\"$2\" class=\"btn $2\">${3: ${2/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}}</button>",
```

If noone points out a mistake, I'll probably file an issue.

---

```
"snippet5": {
  "prefix": "sn5",
  "body": [
     "<button type=\"${1|button,submit|}\" name=\"$2\" class=\"btn $2\">${3: ${2/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}}</button>",
  ],
  "description": "html button"
},
```

An alternative, which requires you to enter the text as `Demo` - note capitalized here, but does select the final tabstop properly without any additional spaces:

`"<button type=\"${1|button,submit|}\" name=\"${2/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}\" class=\"btn ${2/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}\">${3:$2}</button>",`

[image: snippet html demo]

Comment: I think you want `/capitalize`, not `/upcase` (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41526). The OP wants `Demo`, not `DEMO`.

Comment: Oops, thanks. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Oddly I can't get it to work, I don't get the transformation. Is there some magic incantation when using the snippet?

Comment: I posted the full snippet.  You do have to hit `tab` a few times, entering `demo` when it hits the $2 tabstop.

Comment: Huh, it's really weird. I type `sn5` and press tab, it expands, I press tab twice more, type in a name (in lower case), press tab twice more, and the result has the text in lower case (with a space in front of it). I'm using v1.41, which says it's up to date...

Comment: I'll post a gif in a while.

Comment: Thanks @Mark and @T.J.Crowder! The final edit is a workable solution! I'm assuming that vscode snippets are a bit buggy, as I've also run into a similar issue placing tabstops inside of option placeholders like: `"$1 ${2|$1,test|}"` which provides the literal string options of "$1" and "test" instead of the tabstop value for $1 and "test".

Comment: A gif would be great, but only if you have time. (To be clear: I'm not saying the answer is incorrect -- in fact, quite the opposite -- I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working for me locally.)

Comment: The dang gif came out small, expand your screen - it shows all the curious behaviour.